# How to make column chart with JChart2D?

Tags: jchart2d

Example: add (0, y1) point and (0,0) then (20, 0) and (20, y2) and (20, 0), then (30,0) and (30, y3) and (30,0) etc.
so always return to the x axis and step one.

Are there other/better way?

Answer (score 1):

change the default TracePainter of the chart to TracePainterVerticalBar.

try this sample code:

```
public class MinimalStaticChart {

  MinimalStaticChart() {
    super();
  }

  public static void main(String[]args){
    // Create a chart:  
    Chart2D chart = new Chart2D();
    // Create an ITrace: 
    ITrace2D trace = new Trace2DSimple();   
    // change to vertical bar diagram
    trace.setTracePainter(new info.monitorenter.gui.chart.traces.painters.TracePainterVerticalBar(chart));   
    // Add the trace to the chart. This has to be done before adding points (deadlock prevention): 
    chart.addTrace(trace);    
    // Add all points, as it is static: 
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int i=10;i>=0;i--){
      trace.addPoint(i,random.nextDouble()*10.0+i);
    }
    // Make it visible:
    // Create a frame.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MinimalStaticChart");
    // add the chart to the frame: 
    frame.getContentPane().add(chart);
    frame.setSize(400,300);
    // Enable the termination button [cross on the upper right edge]: 
    frame.addWindowListener(
        new WindowAdapter(){
          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
              System.exit(0);
          }
        }
      );
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```